# is there Oracle JRockit 8 version which is equivalent to JDK 1.8 version

Tags: java, java-8, weblogic, jrockit

i have two applications running on Oracle JRockit(build R28.2.2-7-148152-1.6.0_29-20111221-2104-linux-x86_64) java version "1.6.0_29", on Weblogic 11g (both apps running on same server). and now i want to redevelop one application using JDK 1.8. and deploy on same web-logic server.

Q1 : is there Oracle JRockit 8 version which is equivalent to JDK 1.8 ?
Q2 : is it possible to install and configure two JDK/JRE's on same weblogic server as old application runs on Oracle JRockit JRE, and new developed application runson new 1.8 JRE ?

or 
Q3 : if Q2 is not feasible then install new weblogic on same uxix machine in new directory and install JDK 1.8 and deploy newly developed web application on it ?.

Need your expertise.

Comment: There is no “Oracle JRockit 8 version which is equivalent to JDK 1.8”, but there is a “JDK 1.8 from Oracle”.

Comment: i understand that, if i compile my project with JDK 1.8 then i need to install JDK/JRE 1.8 on my unix machine to run my project. but there is no JRockit JRE found equivalent to JDK 1.8. to install. as we should use JRE 1.8 only for runtime.
Thank you for your expertise :)

Comment: There is no “JRockit JRE” and there never will be. Oracle has bought Sun and the entire Java technology with it. There is one JDK/JRE 1.8 from Oracle. It incorporates the JRockit features that Oracle deemed worth the effort of migration. The name “JRockit” is not included.

Comment: Thank you very much Holger :)